# Kubuntu 16.10 + Plasma 5.8 - can't add UK keyboard layout properly!

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, 16.10, plasma

How can I add UK keyboard layout to my Kubuntu 16.10 on Plasma 5.8?

When I **first** installed my Kubuntu, I had the **US keyboard** layout selected and installed into the system.

But now I am using a **UK keyboard** on Microsoft Universal Foldable Keyboard. I have tried to installed to UK keyboard layout from **Keyboard** section. But it does not work properly. For instance:

- When I type `shift+2` I should get a `"` but I get a `@` instead.
- When I type `shift+'` I should get a `@` but I get a `"` instead.
- When I press the `hash` key I can't get the `symbol` but `nothing shows`.

**But:**

- when I press `shift+3` I do get `£`
- When I press `shift+4` I do get `$`

Any ideas why and how I can fix this?

This is what I added to the keyboard layout:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Did I miss anything??

I have tried to change this file below manually but still no luck:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

Content:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

**NOTE 1:**

However, I found something very strange - the keyboard layout **did change** to the UK keyboard layout on my **USB US keyboard**, **but not** changed on my Microsoft Universal Foldable Keyboard! It is only changed to a **semi-UK** keyboard layout. Why!??

Comment: Did you actually switch to the UK layout, e.g. by clicking the layout indicator?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson yes I did. I even have removed the US keyboard and have the machine restarted...

Comment: I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid. Hopefully someone who knows more about Kubuntu can help. I deleted my answer, so others see that the question is unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not coming from the Kubuntu/ Ubuntu. It is from the Microsoft Universal Foldable Keyboard.

I have to switch the the OS to Windows on the keyboard in order to have the UK keyboard layout!

Hope this will help others who use Microsoft's.